# Android Facebook API errors with SSO when Facebook App installed

Tags: android, facebook, single-sign-on

I have been messing with the facebook API/SDK for a while now as I integrate it into an app I am working on. The only real facebook feature I need is checkins, and they work. Most of the time. And here begins my problem.

After looking over the facebook API. I am starting to suspect that either I'm not understanding the API fully, or it is extremely buggy and lacking some important features (like logout?!). 
My main problem with these said bugs is that if I have my application checking in to facebook perfectly (on all accounts, not just developer), and then I install the facebook application in order to change users, then the checkin process through my app will not work unless and until I uninstall the facebook application. I have seen several posts about it, but the topic has to my knowledge never been fully discussed here.

I would normally have been more direct with my question, but I fear I may simply be using the api like a moron, and would like to first make sure that this is an actual issue for others besides just me (especially before I commit to the idea that facebook has no idea what they are doing with the API), and second, see if there is any workaround (maybe even the easy facebook library).
Thanks in advance for any advice and/or confirmation of these issues.

EDIT:
So I ended up using the Easy Android facebook Sdk (http://www.easyfacebookandroidsdk.com/). It has poor documentation, but the examples show you enough of what to do that you can mess with it to work.

But my question about how/why facebook can just not include this in their api still stands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to update my progress with this. I ended up going with the easy facebook android api because even though it has bugs, it is actively developed, and not a utter useless piece of crap.

For any having the same problems of facebook not fixing their software bugs, check out http://www.easyfacebookandroidsdk.com/

Answer (score 2):

This solution worked for me after no other solution did (Cygwin, openssl, wrong alias, wrong password)

The problem is that Windows generates an invalid key.

Run this with your app:

```
try {
   PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("**YOURPACKAGENAME**", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
   for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
        md.update(signature.toByteArray());
        Log.i("PXR", Base64.encodeBytes(md.digest()));
   }
}
catch (NameNotFoundException e) {}
catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {}
```

Don't forget to get Base64 (http://iharder.sourceforge.net/current/java/base64/).

The generated key is on your logcat, replace the old one with this.

Solution thanks to: http://p-xr.com/implementing-facebook-into-your-app-invalid-key-with-keytool/

Answer (score 0):

If you get invalid_key when the FB app is installed its due to the wrong key you're using.
When running keytool with the debug key such as:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

Be sure to enter '`android`' as password, and not your keystore password. To verify, make sure the key that you get is *not* ga0RGNYHvNM5d0SLGQfpQWAPGJ8= but should be something else.

In order to 'logout' try calling `SessionStore.clear()`

Comment: That is one instance where it happens. Try this. Use the correct code and get it so your app works perfectly. Then install the facebook app and try again. 100% of the time in multiple projects, multiple accounts, and multiple devices it gives me that error BECAUSE of the presence of the facebook official app.

Comment: @user627525 where is the "correct code" you are referring to?

Answer (score 0):

As Guy said, an invalid Key Hash may be the problem. In my case, it turns out that was actually it. Jessy, if that is not your problem, you might want to have a look at the error message generated by the AuthListener.

Before logging in, you probably assign an Authentication listener to the session:

```
 SessionEvents.addAuthListener(new FbAPIsAuthListener());
```

Now, just go to the function where you implement the listener and try to catch the error:

```
 /*
 * The Callback for notifying the application when authorization succeeds or
 * fails.
 */

public class FbAPIsAuthListener implements AuthListener {

    @Override
    public void onAuthSucceed() {
        requestUserData();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthFail(String error) {
        //Could not authenticate. Check error message.
        System.out.println("Login error due to " + error)
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.